# Simple Azure Push Service for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, push

I have an Azure project and want to be able to send push notifications to windows phone (7 and 8). I already did this tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-wp8/?fb=de-de

But it didnt helped because I have to send broadcast messages.

I would be nice if there is a Microsoft Push Notification Service where I can register my Azure Service and my Windows Phone App. Then my Azure Service simply could send a message to the MPNS which would broadcast it to all registered windows phones. I mean something like Windows Azure Service Bus Hubs. Unfortunately this Service Bus Hubs dont work with windows phone actually.

Is there something else I could use or am I forced to create such a service all by myself. For example as a WCF Service.

Are there other possibilities? What's the best way to do this? Is there a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [MSDN documentation for Notification Hubs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj927170.aspx), *"[s]upport for Android and Windows Phone will be added soon."*.